# Jquery: How to time an action to start after a different action has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this action:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.SubCategoryList li').each(function(index, element) {
        $(element).append('<div class="ProductListWrapper"></div>')
        var subcategory_link = $(element).find('a').attr('href');
        $(element).find('.ProductListWrapper').load( subcategory_link + ' #CategoryContent ul.ProductList');
     });
 });
```

Works exactly like I intend it too.

I have this other action.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.SubCategoryList .ProductList li').mouseover(function(){
        var ImageSRC = $(this).find(".ProductImage a img").attr('src');
        NewImageSRC = ImageSRC.replace('.200.200.jpg','.400.400.jpg');
        $(this).find('.ProductImage a img').attr('src',NewImageSRC);
        $(this).find('.ProductImage').css('position','relative');
        $(this).find('.ProductImage a img').css('position','absolute').css('top','-50px').css('left','-90px');
    });
    $('.Content .ProductList li').mouseleave(function(){
        var ImageSRC = $(this).find(".ProductImage a img").attr('src');
        NewImageSRC = ImageSRC.replace('.400.400.jpg','.200.200.jpg');
        $(this).find('.ProductImage a img').attr('src',NewImageSRC);
        $(this).find('.ProductImage').css('position','static');
        $(this).find('.ProductImage a img').css('position','static').css('top','auto').css('left','auto');
    });
 });
```

Also works exactly like I intend it to, on console.

But when I try to run I stick them one after the other, they won't work. Is there a way to delay the second one until the first one is done?

Comment: The second 'actions' are event handlers and are only firing when their events are triggered. If you are binding these event handlers to elements that do not exist in the DOM when it is loaded, you should delegate the events using *.on()*

Comment: I think the best solution you have is to delay the event registration till the contents are loaded

Comment: Yes, that sounds like what I want to do, delay event registration

Comment: what is the relationship between SubCategoryList and Content elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the callback for the `$.load()` method. That way, bindings will not be set until the jQuery has finished loading you new DOM elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.SubCategoryList li').each(function(index, element) {
        $(element).append('<div class="ProductListWrapper"></div>')
        var subcategory_link = $(element).find('a').attr('href');
        $(element).find('.ProductListWrapper')
           .load( subcategory_link + ' #CategoryContent ul.ProductList', productHovers);
     });
 });

function productHovers(){
    $('.SubCategoryList .ProductList li').mouseover(function(){
        var ImageSRC = $(this).find(".ProductImage a img").attr('src');
        NewImageSRC = ImageSRC.replace('.200.200.jpg','.400.400.jpg');
        $(this).find('.ProductImage a img').attr('src',NewImageSRC);
        $(this).find('.ProductImage').css('position','relative');
        $(this).find('.ProductImage a img').css('position','absolute').css('top','-50px').css('left','-90px');
    });
    $('.Content .ProductList li').mouseleave(function(){
        var ImageSRC = $(this).find(".ProductImage a img").attr('src');
        NewImageSRC = ImageSRC.replace('.400.400.jpg','.200.200.jpg');
        $(this).find('.ProductImage a img').attr('src',NewImageSRC);
        $(this).find('.ProductImage').css('position','static');
        $(this).find('.ProductImage a img').css('position','static').css('top','auto').css('left','auto');
    });

}
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Will accept as answer as soon as it lets me